# getting error with this makefile

Tags: makefile

I can't understand what the problem is with this makefile?
I'm getting error `` No rule to make target `step.c', needed by `step.o'.  Stop. ``

```
vertex: main.o step.o
    gcc main.o step.o -o vertex 

main.o: main.c header.h
    gcc -c main.c

step.o: step.c header.h
    gcc -c step.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a file `step.c` so Make thinks you want it to generate one, but it doesn't know how.